# Плагин "Читать далее"

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте, начал изучать jquery. Пишу первый плагин "Читать далее", то есть 
хочу чтобы изначально блок был `15px` высоту, а при нажатии на ссылку, блок с анимацией открылся полностью, и по повторному нажатию на кнопку блок сворачивается  .

Вот к чему я пришел (прошу не кричать, что гавнокод и т.д.)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#show_more').toggle(
    function(){
       $("#show_desc").animate({
        height: auto
      }, 500 );
    $('#show_more').text('Свернуть');
    },  function(){
        $("#show_desc").animate({
        height: '15px'
      }, 500 );
      $('#show_more').text('Читать далее');
    }
)
});
</script>

<a href="#" id="show_more">Свернуть</a>
<div id="show_desc" style="height: 15px;">text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text </div>
```

Но что-то как-то не то :) Рад услышать ваши варианты либо поправки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

height: "auto" - нужно в кавычки

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#show_more').toggle(
    function(){
       $("#show_desc").animate({
        height: "15px"
      }, 500 );
    $('#show_more').text('Свернуть');
    },  function(){
        $("#show_desc").animate({
        height: $("#inner").height()+'px'
      }, 500 );
      $('#show_more').text('Читать далее');
    }
)
});
</script>

<a href="#" id="show_more">Свернуть</a>
<div id="show_desc" style="height: 15px;overflow:hidden"><div id="inner">text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text </div></div>
```

Comment: только auto здесь не очень подходить, потому то после height: '15px' - auto будет 15px

Comment: как то не правильно работает. при одном нажатии, пропадает сразу весь текст и сразу же появляется

Comment: Лучше использовать внешний блок - а относительно его и брать height.

Comment: А можете отредактировать мой код? =)

Comment: Спасибо,только в вашем примере функции в toggle я поменял местами : )
и все отлично.

Answer (score 0):

`overflow: hidden;` Вам в помошь!
При клике развернуть, для `height` лучше задавать пустое значение, и убирать `overflow`. При клике свернуть вернуть все в исходное!